# Get underlying NSWindow from gtk.Window

Tags: macos, pygtk, pyobjc

The following is about gtk2 with the Quartz backend on Mac. If I have a gtk.Window (or a gdk.Window), how do I get the underlying NSWindow (preferably as a pyobjc object, or if that's not possible, just a pointer)?

(I'm trying to get [window windowNumber], which is needed to enable blur-behind transparent windows.)

Comment: Since you accepted houbysoft's answer I was wondering if you managed it to call `gdk_quartz_window_get_nswindow()`? I always get a Segfault, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669176/get-the-window-handle-in-pygi-on-macos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the exact name of the function in pygtk, but I believe that in C you can call `gdk_quartz_window_get_nswindow()`.