# Get the window handle in PyGI on MacOS

Tags: macos, ctypes, gtk3, pygobject, python-gstreamer

I use PyGObject/PyGI and GStreamer to show a video in my GUI. The video is shown in a Gtk.DrawingArea and therefore I need to get it's window-handle in the realize-signal-handler. On Linux I can simply use `drawing_area.get_property('window').get_xid()` and on Windows I have to access the C-API (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823541/get-the-window-handle-in-pygi)):

```
drawingarea_window = drawingarea.get_property('window')
ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
drawingarea_gpointer = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer(drawingarea_window.__gpointer__, None)
gdkdll = ctypes.CDLL ('libgdk-3-0.dll')
self._drawingarea_handle = gdkdll.gdk_win32_window_get_handle(drawingarea_gpointer)
```

Now I want the same on MacOS. Since it is not using X11, but Quartz, I tried to use the C-API again. But this time to call `gdk_quartz_window_get_nswindow` instead of `gdk_win32_window_get_handle` (see [gdkwindow-quartz.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gdk/quartz/gdkwindow-quartz.c#L111)):

```
// ... same lines as in Windows-example
gdkdll = ctypes.CDLL ('libgdk-3.0.dylib')
self._drawingarea_handle = gdkdll.gdk_quartz_window_get_nswindow(drawingarea_gpointer)
```

But this leads just to a `Segmentation fault: 11`.
Any ideas on how to get the handle on MacOS?

Comment: I did some research into this, the only big difference I can find between your code and other code that uses `gdk_quartz_window_get_nswindow` is that in other examples (in C#) pass a window handle to this function. Like here: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/MacPlatform/MacInterop/GtkQuartz.cs#L56

Comment: But the window handle is what I want to retrieve. So I cannot pass it to the function ;) The source-file you linked uses `GdkWindow.Handle`. In my example `drawingarea_window` is of type `GdkWindow`. However this object does not contain a `handle`/`Handle` property/attribute.

Comment: @Biggie Did you get an answer for this???

Comment: Unfortunately not :(